# What happens when when the start value of a python substring command is negative?

Tags: python

Example:

```
mystring = " ... some string ... "
mystring[-50:40]  # <--- what does this mean?
```

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: -1 for lazy-attitude. You can figure that out yourself *before* asking

Comment: this question is totally not cool user72023452354...

Comment: @RestRisiko: you're being too harsh. Trying and seeing isn't the same as understanding what's going on. As it happens, this particular behavior of Python isn't trivial and it's worth asking about.

Comment: It's not about being trivial - it's about showing a minimum amount of motivation trying about things about - nothing more nothing else. And stop people complaining about people with zero motivation. Wrong person for the job....

Answer (score 7):

Negative indexes in a slice count from the right. Yes, even for the start value.

```
>>> '12345'[-4:4]
'234'
```

Comment: I have a sinking feeling that somewhere I have written Python code that assumed something different...

Answer (score 1):

Negative indexes *in general* have an implied `len(of_this_object)` added to the negative index. Doesn't matter if they are *start*, *end* or plain indexes.

Example:

```
some_object[10:-20]
```

is interpreted as meaning:

```
some_object[10:len(some_object)-20]
```

This is why:

```
some_object[-1]
```

means the last item in `some_object`.